# Does map::iterator yield lvalues?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, containers

In other words, when `i` is a `map<K,V>::iterator`, do the following provide the expected semantics (ie. it modifies the map):

```
*i = make_pair(k, v);
i->first = k;
i->second = v;
```

?

**Update:** The first two lines are invalid, since the return value of `operator*` is (convertible to?) a `pair<const K, V>`. What about the third line ?

Assuming a *yes* answer to the three, this would imply that:

- Either `map<K,V>` elements are stored as a `pair<K,V>` somewhere,
- Or there is some clever proxy class which `map<K,V>::iterator::operator*` returns. In this case, how is `operator->` implemented ?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/utility/make_pair/ -

Comment: @DumbCoder: I'd like to know whether `*i` returns a *reference* to a pair object, or a pair object, or some proxy classes convertible to `pair`, but which provides lvalue semantics.

Comment: > Debugged it and shows a templatized pair object, being constructed and returned.

Comment: The important point is: you cannot (without resorting to drastic measures) change map keys through iterators, because that would potentially violate the map's invariants.

Comment: @Fred: Yep, I just found this somewhere on the net. But this doesn't change fundamentally the question; there is a second member in the pair.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to track this down through the standard:

- For a `map<Key,T>` the `value_type` is `pair<const Key,T>` per 23.3.1/2
- The map class supports bidirectional iterators, per 23.3.1/1
- bidirectional iterator satisfies the requirements for forward iterators, per 24.1.4/1
- For a forward iterator `a` with `value_type` `T`, expression `*a` returns **T&** (not a type "convertible to T", as some other iterators do) (Table 74 in 24.1.3)

Therefore, the requirement is to return a reference to pair, and not some other proxy type.

Comment: Great. This limits somewhat the implementation, interesting. Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

map is almost like a set of pairs. Yes, it's iterator is probably implemented as a pointer to a node with a `pair<const K,V>`. **However** your code is invalid, because the values are actually of type `pair<const K, V>` so you can't assign to `first`.

*i returns `pair<const K, V>&` <strike>or some proxy that behaves like this type</strike> (can't find a backup of the last claim in the standard). You can implement such proxies by overloading `operator ->`.

Comment: Nope, lvalue/rvalue is a distinction of *expressions*, not of objects. See [ISO03, 3.10 basic.lval §1]. There can be multiple lvalues and rvalues denoting the same object.

Comment: Moreover, I don't see the problem with the formulation of my question. I think I know what a lvalue is.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, technically the unary `*` operator evaluates to an lvalue in this case. However, the term lvalue in C basically designates something that has location (address) in storage (memory). In C++ terminology even functions are *lvalues*. So, again, in your example above the unary `*` yield an lvalue. You can take the address of that lvalue, if you wish to do so, i.e. you can evaluate `&*i`, `&i->first` and `&i->second` (assuming the built-in unary `&`).

Secondly, since you original example involves assignment, you must be actually talking about *modifiable lvalues*. You see, the property of being *lvalue* by itself has very little to do with being assignable. To use the built-in assignment operator, you need a *modifiable lvalue*. What you get from a dereferenced iterator is `value_type` of `std::map`. It is a pair with a const-qualified first member, as you know already. This automatically makes the first member non-modifiable, and this makes the entire pair non-modifiable by the built-in assignment operator. The second member of the pair is modifiable, as you observed yourself already.

So, once again, the dereference operator in this case returns an lvalue. This lvalue is non-modifiable as a whole, and its first member is non-modifiable as well. Its second member is a modifiable lvalue.

As for your assumption about how the elements of `std::map` are stored, I would say that in a typical implementation they will be stored as `pair<const K, V>` objects, i.e. exactly what the dereference operator evaluates to. Normally, the map does not need to modify the key portion of the pair after it is initialized, so it should not run into any problems with the fact that the first member of the pair is const-qualified.

Comment: Thanks for the nitpicking, but it doesn't answer the question. Does assigning to the second member change the map ?

Comment: @Alex: The answer is yes. But why didn't you just try it for yourself?

Comment: @Alexandre C.: I don't see the "does it change the map" question in the OP, but the answer is yes, it does change the map.

Comment: I thought "expected semantics" was a clear formulation. @Fred: I want to know if it is _standard_. A given implementation could be free to implement lvalue semantics if the standard says nothing (or UB).

Answer (score 1):

```
map<K,V>::iterator i = my_map.begin();

*i = make_pair(k, v); // invalid, you cannot assign to a pair<const K,V>&
i->first = k; // invalid cannot write to const
i->second = v; // valid
```

Comment: @Alexandre: Paul is right. You cannot write to a `std::map<K,V>::value_type`, no matter whether the iterator is valid. The reason is that `std::map<K,V>::value_type` expands to `std::pair<const K,V>` (note the `const`), which, while it is an lvalue, still cannot be written to. `+1` from me to counter the pointless down-vote.

Comment: Paul, I've taken the liberty to edit your answer to make it clearer. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Alexander thanks, that's very kind. But, please, next time read the answer carefully before you downvote. @sbi no problem.